# 'Someone who hops from idea to idea'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word or a term used for someone who hops from idea to idea?

More specifically, for someone who jumps from idea to idea without ever really completing any of them.

Comment: Always mention the question in the body. Mentioning in the title is not enough.

Comment: **Why** does the person move from idea to idea? Indecisiveness? Lack of commitment? Easily bored? Easily frustrated? Easily swayed? Opportunistic? I might pick different words depending on the answers to such questions: _waffler, trifler, quitter, dropout, pushover, impressionable, opportunist, pioneer..._ I think you should add some more details about what kind of word you're after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*A dabbler* might fit. Thesaurus dot com offers a bevy of synonyms, from which I'd pick *a tinkerer*. If solely intellectual effort is implied, *a scatterbrain* may be it. Turning to adjectives, *fickle-minded* sounds fine to me. P.S. Found another adjective: *[flaky](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flaky)*

Russians tend to say that someone has "[seven Fridays in a week](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1396/1884)".

Answer (score 2):

A **dilettante**.

**Desultory** fits if adjectives are acceptable.

Comment: Wouldn't a person who is *desultory" be a desultorer (or desultoress, depending on gender to be implied)?

Comment: If those are dictionary words, yes. Are they? English isn't omni-productive. So I probably shouldn't have used that term either.

Comment: Every construct that should be a word in English is already one - some just haven't ever been used yet.

Comment: Your definition of _word_ is non-standard, and your tacit assumption that some subset of Anglophones is better qualified to decide on 'what should be a word' unwarranted.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the OED’s definitions of *butterfly* are: ‘a light-headed, inconstant person’ and ‘applied to persons whose periods of work or occupation of a place are transitory or seasonal.’ With careful handling, you might be able to use the word in the sort of context you have in mind.

Comment: Yes; 'He has a butterfly mentality' is not unknown (though I expected more hits on Google, I admit).

Answer (score 1):

**Scatter-brained**, or simply **scattered**, come to mind: