# short-lived enthusiasm

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

How to describe a person who has initiative and enthusiasm to start new activities but their fervor shortly quenches and they pick up new activities. In my neighborhood we say "he has got a **straw ignition**." It means he is a quitter but it emphasizes good positive short-lived enthusiasm.

There is an idiom "a flash in the pan" but I do not think it is appropriate to describe a person. It originates from reflecting light of pyrite or sparkling water in the sickle used for finding gold. So it is false good start in a situation rather than a person characteristic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm looking for a word that's like a whimsical fanatic someone who dives in to something for a period of time and then moves on](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409510/im-looking-for-a-word-thats-like-a-whimsical-fanatic-someone-who-dives-in-to-s) (This was closed as a duplicate of [someone who hops from idea to idea](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138853/someone-who-hops-from-idea-to-idea), which included the 'phrase' tag.)

Comment: *It originates from reflecting light of pyrite* No, It is military and refers to flintlocks: 1810   C. James New Military Dictionary (ed. 3)    **Flash in the pan, an explosion of gunpowder without any communication beyond the touch-hole.** OED "flash in the pan *figurative* an abortive effort or outburst."

Comment: @Greybeard Isn't your origin even more negative? Wouldn't be there any more positive phrase to describe a person's short-lived passion. I want to emphasize the heat of that enthusiasm.

Comment: A sprinter, not a marathon runner?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Yes, it is. I was merely correcting the etymology. (The one you gave is common but wrong.) *Short-lived enthusiasm* is not seen as positive, and this presents a big problem. There is a  phrase similar to yours by Shakespeare "soon kindled and soon burned" (KHiv P1 III.2) and it is negative.

Comment: @YosefBaskin *A sprinter, not a marathon runner.* Brilliant! (Although there's a whiff of the "damning by faint praise" about it. :)

Comment: From Lao Tzu: *The flame that burns twice as bright burns half as long.* (A variant appears in *Blade Runner*.) However, that's another expression that doesn't directly apply to a person.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Someone who hops from idea to idea'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138853/someone-who-hops-from-idea-to-idea)

Comment: @KillingTime all the answers provided in suggested similar questions emphasize the negative side of the huge but short-lived enthusiasm trait. For example, suggested scattered or quitter - someone can be "scattered" but it does not mean that he is enthusiastic at the first stage of the project before he quits it.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is **shiny object syndrome**, sometimes called **bright shiny object syndrome**. If you Google it, you'll get lot's of hits, e.g., https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/288370, https://productiveclub.com/shiny-object-syndrome/. I'd describe "a person who has initiative and enthusiasm to start new activities but their fervor shortly quenches and they pick up new activities" as having **shiny object syndrome**.